# How to play mp3 url in the background in reactjs app?

Tags: reactjs, mp3, audio-streaming, autoplay-media-studio

How do you add a mp3 url to your reactjs app and let it autoPlay in loop in the background?

I installed both reactplayer and react audio player packages.

Here's my code:

```
import "./App.css";
import ReactAudioPlayer from "react-audio-player";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ReactAudioPlayer
        src="https://www.mboxdrive.com/SolarSymphony.mp3"
        autoPlay
        loop
      />
    </div>
);
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Have no idea what `ReactAudioPlayer` is, but you can just use a normal audio element for this.

Comment: It is an nom package installed: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-audio-player

I tried different ways not no luck. nI even added the audio to a mp4 video to run and that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can **load an mp3** file **from an audio element**.

1. Make sure you move your `music.mp3` into the `/public` folder.
   [image]
2. Add an `audio` element inside the `<body>` of your `index.html`

   ```html
   <audio id="audio" loop autoplay> 
     <source src="%PUBLIC_URL%/music.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
   </audio>
   ```

**Done!**

If you want to control the audio to `Play/Pause/Stop` the music.

```
const audio: Partial<HTMLAudioElement> = document.getElementById('audio')

audio.pause()
```

You can call this from anywhere, remember to remove `autoplay` prop from the audio element if you don't want it to play when the app starts.